# Changing what the close button does

Tags: skype

Is there was way to make the close (X) button more like the one in Windows or at least change it's properties to same as the minimize button? It's really annoying signing into Steam, exiting the window just to have to sign in again and again or recall people on Skype over a simple click.

There is already a question relating to this but doesn't have an actual answer to it. :/

Comment: With "more like […] in Windows" you mean that the application window is closed bot the application keeps running as a small notification icon in the taskbar, correct? Whether this is done depends mostly on the application. Did you check if `steam` or `skype` have any settings for that? ("Minimize on close" or something like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on the default Ubuntu or Ubuntu GNOME, you can simply remove the close button from the list, leaving only minimize and maximize:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout
'close,minimize,maximize:'
```

So do:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'minimize,maximize:'
```

Answer (score 1):

What actually happens when the close button is clicked, depends on the program.

In my Ubuntu 14.04 both Steam and Skype are minimized to a tray icon, and keep running. So this is most likely a misconfiguration of these applications, and not the fault of Gtk+ or Qt.

Comment: So theres no 100% way to universally change the function of the button? How do I reconfigure it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should look at the Settings of those individual programs. You may find an option to configure this.